# Groups acting properly discontinuous and cocompactly on the hyperbolic plane by isometries.

Tags: geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

I'm looking for a non-elementary hyperbolic group which is quasi isometric to $\mathbb{H}^2$ (and if possible one quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{H}^3$).

I know the group $\text{PSL}(\mathbb{R})$ acts by isometries on $\mathbb{H}^2$ via the maps
$$ z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}. $$
Is it then true that $\text{PSL}(\mathbb{Z})$ as a subgroup acts properly discontinuously and cocompactly on $\mathbb{H}^2$ and by consequence (Svarc-Milnor lemma) $\text{PSL}(\mathbb{Z})$ would be the group I'm looking for? At least if this group is a non-elementary hyperbolic group which I'm also not sure of.

Comment: You may want to edit the terminology in your post" **quasi-isometric** instead of *quasi-isomorphic*, $PSL(2, {\mathbb R})$ instead of $PSL({\mathbb R})$. Also, in English, if you ask a question in a sentence, you add the sentence with the question mark. On the substantive side, yes, $PSL(2, {\mathbb Z})$ is non-elementary hyperbolic and no, it is not quasi-isometric to the hyperbolic plane. Do you know that every compact connected oriented surface of genus $\ge 2$ admits a hyperbolic metric?

Comment: No I did not know that, but I guess you want to argue that the fundamental group of such a manifold is an example of such a group I am looking for?

Comment: Exactly: You should think what the universal cover of such surface (with the pull-back metric) would be isometric to. In fact, the examples of hyperbolic surfaces is where all the concepts you are reading about originated from.

Comment: Ok. Is there some similar statement like: 'Do you know that every compact connected oriented surface of genus ≥2 admits a hyperbolic metric?' but then for 3-dimensional manifolds?

Comment: Yes, there is! It was a remarkable conjecture by Thurston proven Perelman, and for which he refused to accept all those prizes given to him. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrization_conjecture

Comment: A deep theorem from the 1980-90s states that for a finitely generated group $\Gamma$, the following are equivalent: (i) $\Gamma$ is QI to $\mathbf{H}^2$; (ii) $\Gamma$ has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to the fundamental group of some closed surface (iii) $\Gamma$ has a maximal normal finite subgroup $W$, and $\Gamma/W$ is isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{R})$; (iv) $\Gamma$ admits a proper cocompact isometric action on $\mathbf{H}^2$. (That each of (ii),(iii),(iv) implies (i) being easy.)

Comment: Another theorem (using other methods) in dimension 3 is the equivalence (i') $\Gamma$ is QI to $\mathbf{H}^3$; (iii') $\Gamma$ has a maximal normal finite subgroup $W$, and $\Gamma/W$ is isomorphic to a cocompact lattice in $\mathrm{PO}(3,1)$; (iv') $\Gamma$ admits a proper cocompact isometric action on $\mathbf{H}^3$. [I'm skipping (ii') because I'm not sure that each such group is known to have a torsion-free subgroup of finite index, although I'm sure that it's either true or unknown.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most explicit examples of groups quasi-isometric to the hyperbolic 3-space are certain **Coxeter groups.** Coxeter groups are best described by their **Coxeter diagrams**, such as the one below:

[image]

This diagram describes a group with four generators (corresponding to the nodes). The relators are:

1. Each generator $s_v$ is an involution, $s_v^2=1$.
2. If two nodes $v, w$ are not connected by an edge, the corresponding generators commute: $s_v s_w=s_w s_v$.
3. If two nodes $v, w$ are connected by an unlabelled edge, then the generators "braid":
   $$
   (s_vs_w)^3=1  
   $$
4. If two nodes $v, w$  are connected by an edge with the label $n$ (in the graph below, $n=5$) then 
   $$
   (s_vs_w)^n=1
   $$

The Coxeter group described by the diagram above acts isometrically, properly discontinuously and cocompactly on the hyperbolic 3-space (this takes some work to prove, the key is the existence of the corresponding [Goursat tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat_tetrahedron) in ${\mathbb H}^3$). Hence, this Coxeter group is a (necessarily nonelementary hyperbolic group) quasi-isometric to ${\mathbb H}^3$.